# Upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10, GRUB boot no longer working properly

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

Since upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 on my Lenovo T500 laptop my GRUB boot does not work properly anymore. If I select Ubuntu *Low Latency* or Ubuntu from the menu it just reboots again, so is basically just an endless boot loop. However if I select Advanced Options then any of the subsequent options it boots through to 17.10 desktop fine.

So clearly the standard GRUB boot options no longer point to the correct boot sequence (or however it works in Ubuntu !). Whilst it's not a huge problem because there is a work-around it's still annoying since it has worked fine in every previous version (and I've been running Ubuntu Studio for nearly two years now, and had thought it was an excellent distro.....)

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall GRUB?

Comment: Try sudo update-grub